# Master ViewController becomes blank after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I make MGSplitViewController by

`MySplitViewController = [[MGSplitViewController alloc] init];
[MySplitViewController setViewControllers:@[masterVC, detailVC]];`

After rotation from portrait to landscape on iPad masterVC presents as blank space. In view hierarchy I see that it's only background window and no masterVC on it. DetailVC presents correctly.

Help me, plz.

Answer (score 0):

When your ipad is on portrait mode, you have a popover of your master.
What means that you are presenting a modal using this popover as presentingViewController, so when you move from portrait to landscape the method splitViewController:willShowViewController will make your popover nil as you can see:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController )splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController )viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
    {
        // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
        self.masterPopoverController = nil;
    }
```